# Logic app : How to merge multiple response using each loop

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using 1 3rd party service which provides me 500 records at a time, but I want all records together in single request. I've integrated that part using Each loop [image] this is how my for each loop looks like

When I tried to fetch all response using Array, the data is not strucutred, Array appends whole JSON which of response as object which looks like this

```
[{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
object 1
        }]
},
{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
object 2
        }]
}]
```

Now what I want is

```
[{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
 object 1
        },
        {
object 2
        },
        {
object 3
         }
}]
```

I have no idea how to merge this data in logic app, can some one please guide how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show details about your flow, so maybe you could refer to my below flow. To mock you situation, I use http trigger to get the json data. Be low is my test json data. If this is not what you want please feel free to let me know.

```
[{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "PSI"
    }]
},
{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 1,
      "lookup": "CLEAN"
    }]
}]
```

Firstly I parse the json data from the trigger body, the initiate a array variable to store the array after formatting.

[image]

Then loop the json data, formatting the array. If all your `data` property only have one object json in the array, you could append the array with `items('For_each')['data'][0]`, if not you need another `For each` to loop the `data` array.

[image]

Then get the result json value you want, cause you just want one json object and your json values are same except the `data` property. So I use a `compose` action to henerate the json. I set the value with `setProperty(body('Parse_JSON')[0],'data',variables('array'))`.

[image]

Here is my test result, hope this is what you want.

[image]

**Update**: If I didn't misunderstand, your data array has more than one object and you want to get them all, If right just like have mentioned you need another `For each` action to loop the array then append all of them to the variable, you could refer to below flow.

All other actions are same, add a `For each` in the exist `For each`.

[image]

Here is my test result. Below is the json data I sent to logic app.

```
[{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "PSI"
    },{
        "count": 3,
      "lookup": "TEST"
    }]
},
{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 1,
      "lookup": "CLEAN"
    },{
        "count": 4,
      "lookup": "GET"
    }]
}]
```

[image]

**Update2**: Below is my test json and the result:

```
[{ 
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [ 
        [
            { "count" : 0, "lookup": "test0" },
            { "count": 1, "lookup": "test1" }
        ], 
        [ 
            { "count": 2, "lookup": "test2" },
            { "count": 3, "lookup": "test3" }
        ]
    ] 
},{ 
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [ 
        [
            { "count" : 4, "lookup": "test4" },
            { "count": 5, "lookup": "test5" }
        ], 
        [ 
            { "count": 6, "lookup": "test6" },
            { "count": 7, "lookup": "test7" }
        ]
    ] 
}]
```

Just add one more for each action.

[image]

[image]

**Update**: to send the http response with json data, you could use Response action to do it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi George, your formula worked but still having 1 more issue, I'm executing a loop to fetch all records from service and appending data in Array, Array now consist of different object. How I can extract those object in a single data [] thing, the last thing if you can help me this will be resolved.

Comment: @V.V, I have updated my answer, hope this is what you want, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know. And if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hi George, noo My data comes from first for loop is like this [{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "PSI"
    },{
        "count": 3,
      "lookup": "TEST"
    }]
}],
[{
    "total": 628,
    "start": 0,
    "count": 500,
    "data": [
        {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "PSI"
    },{
        "count": 3,
      "lookup": "TEST"
    }]
}]

so there are 2 different index in array, that's the main issue here. AS I need to call web service in loop to fetch more records.

Comment: there is also another issue when I execute for loop inside for loop, system is taking too much time to process data for all records execution

Comment: @V.V,Please provide a correct json sample, and the json format in your comment is different from the question's, so make sure what you want. About logic app took too much time, do you have a huge data.

Comment: ```{
    [ 
   [{
       "count" : 0,
       "lookup": "PSI"
     },{
         "count": 3,
       "lookup": "TEST"
  }],
  [ 
      {
        "count": 0,
        "lookup": "PSI"
      },{
          "count": 3,
        "lookup": "TEST"
  }],
  [ 
      {
        "count": 0,
        "lookup": "PSI"
      },{
          "count": 3,
        "lookup": "TEST"
  }]
 ]
 }```

This is how the array is looking like after calling multiple services to get records. (sorry for later response) In each request I'll get 500 records, there are 7-8 loops for getting allrecords

Comment: @V.V, I have updated it, check it, hope this is what you want?

Comment: Noo , yesterday I tried but in for loops due to huge data logic app is constantly moving and not able to complete the loop due to huge data each loop has 500 records and there are 7 loops, So here only simple thing wanted to know, if we can store data instead array ? and then merge it some where using logic app. Because any how we'll execute it using for loop is not a good idea for huge data, like right now having 4000 records for demo in production it can be 10 or 20k in a loop.

Comment: What do you mean ` if we can store data instead array `? Even store data however there is still many loops suppose won't shorten the execution time.

Comment: Like wise when I execute 3 for each as you have explained, the system didn't provide the output and it was in infinite loop. I've created an API to read this data, that API shoed some error that there is something wrong with Logic app. That's why Asked instead for each if there is another way to do the same thing !

Comment: Logic app was in infinite loop, didn't show timeout error?

Comment: Yes when executed logic app it didn't show any error I waited till 3 mins and then had terminated the Logic app.

Comment: So your other action works fine, just stuck with the for each action and could get full data from your service. Would you mind don't terminate it manually until it timeout or show other errors?

Comment: And I am not very clear about store data, where you want to store, in what format?

Comment: I need all data in json formate, I want to get data from 3rd party web service and merge all data which is in chunk of 500 records in single response, in total it will be more that 5K any time. Yes you are correct it's just and issue with For Each all other things seems good. 

let me execute my Logic app and wait till any error comes in.

Comment: You mean after the `compose` action you want to store the data, if yes you could, azure blob, ftp etc.

Comment: yes correct, I want to send the composed data as HTTP response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212131/discussion-between-v-v-and-george-chen).

Comment: Thanks @George Chen for your support and time to resolve this.